# Domain Help - Inputting Admin Credentials when prompted breaks user syncing

Tags: windows-server-2003

Couldn't quite describe the full problem within the Title...

Basically, on our domain we'll have a user sign in with their login (Example: Joe Bloggs would log in as "JBloggs"). They don't have administrator rights, and need the servers admin details inputting when trying to install/update something. This has caused a strange issue which I'll try to explain.

JBloggs attempts to Update his piece of software, but is prompted for admin user/pass, so when inputted; anything JBloggs tries to save to his desktop, will attempt to save it to /user/admin/desktop rather than user/Jbloggs/desktop, even though on the start menu it clearly shows JBloggs is still logged in.

The only workaround / solution I've found so far is to restart the machine and log into your profile, this happens everytime someone is prompted for admin rights.

Any Solutions?

Using a Windows server, all/most machines run Windows 7/8

Comment: `JBloggs attempts to Update his piece of software, but is prompted for admin user/pass, so when inputted; anything JBloggs tries to save to his desktop,` Expand on this, please.  It's not clear exactly what's happening.  Though, generally, users having admin credentials is not good... so I'd solve the problem by removing admin rights.

Comment: Basically, we restrict users from having admin rights, so when they try to install something it prompts them for the Admin User/Pass where they have to ring up an IT Admin to come insert it for them.

Then, once this has been input and the user begins to install the software they needed admin rights for; everything they try to save/create is defaulting to the Admins directory (Let's say admins profile is ADM1N, it'll attempt to save the file they've been working on into the /user/ADM1N/Desktop location)